# Is Unlockable Content in a gifted Opensea NFT safe to open?

Tags: wallets, erc-721, nft

If a 10 of 10 edition NFT is sent as a gift to your, and several other peoples', wallets on OpenSea (a custom token engineered by the issuer, and not a well-known NFT platform's token class), is it safe to unlock the unlockable content?

I ask because opening unlockable content costs gas, meaning there is a contract interaction going which could be disguising nefarious privileges granted to the gifter. Is there any possibility the issuer of the gifted NFT can gain access to the rest of your wallet and steal your other NFTs or Eth in your wallet somehow?

I identify two security risks:

- Paying gas and possibly opening a backdoor to your wallet upon unlocking the content
- Opening the file, attachment or link that is finally unlocked